# upload fail to s3 fails without description

Tags: amazon-s3

I do not understand why it fails, I was able to upload yesterday, but not today (the file is only 15MB).

[image]

[image]

How come they have 0 description for the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It failed several times using firefox. With Chrome I was able to upload it.